# How to do the diagonal decomposition of this matrix?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Given a matrix G as a N*N symmetric matrix, in which

---

$$G_{ij} = \begin{cases}
           \sum_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{R_{ij}},  &\quad \mbox{if j = i} \\      
           -\frac{1}{R_{ij}},                &\quad \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

$R_{ii}$ and $R_{ij}$ are greater than $0$ and $R_{ii}>R_{ij}$. Matrix $G$ is a symmetric diagonal dominant matrix.

how to do the eigen-decompostion? to transfer this matrix to $G = W D W^{-1} $format, where D is a diagonal N*N matrix.

Since matrix G is a symmetric matrix, thus $W^{-1} = W^{T}$, where$ W^{T} $ means the transpose of $W$.

I tried that let $W = 1_{N \times N}$, $W$ is $N$*$N$ matrix with all the elements being $1$, but it seems not correct.

So, how to write a general term of $W$ toward this $N$*$N$ matrix? Thank you.

Comment: without knowing more about $R_{i,j}$ it is hard to say.

Comment: Thank you for your response. We know R_{i,j} = R{j,i} and R_11 = R_22=...= R_ii

Comment: In addition, all the R are real number

Comment: Why is $G$ not diagonal dominant? The diagonal element is the sum of the absolute value of the non diagonal element plus some positiv number.

Comment: Sorry, G is diagonal dominant.